# Retrieve the NICs and the associated VMs in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell, azure-virtual-network

I need to retrieve the NICs and the associated VMs in Azure
I've run the following Cmdlet:

```
Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface | Select Name, VirtualMachine
```

But, it only generate the names of the NICs but when it come to the Virtual Machine it displays Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.Models.PSResourceId, as shown in the following figure.[image: Virtual Machine Output]

Please advise how to retrieve the actual name of the VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please advise how to retrieve the actual name of the VM.

We could use the [select-object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6) to do that. It works correctly for me.

```
Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface |  Select-Object -Property Name, @{Name="VMName";Expression = {$_.VirtualMachine.Id.tostring().substring($_.VirtualMachine.Id.tostring().lastindexof('/')+1)}}
```

[image]

**Update** : according to the comment

If we want to get the virtual network name we could use the command

```
Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork
```

How to export the result in the same csv file. We could use [out-file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-6)

```
Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork | select Name |out-file $filePath -Append
Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface |  Select-Object -Property Name, @{Name="VMName";Expression = {$_.VirtualMachine.Id.tostring().substring($_.VirtualMachine.Id.tostring().lastindexof('/')+1)}} |out-file $filePath -Append
```

Comment: Thank you Tom. What about the Subnet Name, and is there is a way to retrieve the virtual network name in the same cmdlet?

Comment: If you want to get the virtual network name, you could use the cmdlet [Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.network/get-azurermvirtualnetwork?view=azurermps-6.1.0).

Comment: I need them in the same result. Can I export all of these info in the same csv?

Comment: Yes.  we could export all of them into the same csv.  I will update the answer.

Comment: But I believe that this would match the right virtual networks with the right NICs, right?